# How to print logs during jest tests when I need to mock console.log as part of testing?

Tags: jestjs

I want to print some things to console while testing with Jest, to check values, but at the same time, I need to mock the `console.log` function because I want to check that a function I am testing tries to call it.

I thought Jest would have its own function to print some logs to the console as part of testing, but I can't find anything like it.

By mocking console.log I lose the ability to log things to the console for debugging purposes. Is there some way around this?

Comment: You would want to spy on it rather than mocking. So something like: let consoleLogSpy = jest.spyOn(console, “log”). Then you can expect the spy to “haveBeenCalledWith” or “haveBeenCalledTimes”. Mocking changes the function, spying keeps it the same.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point, you can post it as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: Sure, see my answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66759244/4298115). Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to **spy** on it rather than *mocking*.

So something like:

`let consoleLogSpy = jest.spyOn(console, “log”)`.

Then you can do:

`expect(consoleLogSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)`

and/or

`expect(consoleLogSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(“text”)`.

#### Main takeaway

> Mocking changes the function, spying keeps it the same.